# subpage loaded through ajax is killing jquery functionality

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm working on a site, http://teneo.telegraphbranding.com/, and I am hoping to load the pages via ajax so that the sidebar and its animation remain consistent.

When the 'About' link is clicked I need it to load about2.php via a jquery ajax function. But I'm not having any luck. When I can get the page to load via ajax it kills all the jquery functionality on the page. From what I've read I think I need to call the jquery upon successful completion of the ajax call.

I've tried everything it seems and can't get it work. What I need is about2.php to load when the link is clicked and the jquery to dynamically size the divs, like it does on the homepage.
I tried this, but it won't even load the page:

```
//Dropdown
$(document).ready(function () {
var dropDown = $('.dropdown');
$('h3.about').on('click', function() {
    dropDown.slideDown('fast', function() {
        var url = 'about2.php'

        $.get(url, function(data) {

        //anything in this block runs after the ajax call

            var missionWrap = $('#mission-wrap');
            var w = $(window);
            w.on('load resize',function() {
                missionWrap.css({ width:w.width(), height:w.height()});
            });
            var missionContent = $('#mission-content');
            var w = $(window);
            w.on('load resize',function() {
                missionContent.css({ width:w.width() - 205 });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

});

And then this loads the page, but kills all the jQuery associated with it:

```
var dropDown = $('.dropdown');
$('h3.about').on('click', function() {
    dropDown.slideDown('fast', function() {
        $('#index-wrap').load('/about2.php');
    });
});
```

Thank you very much.

I also tried this and it just broke everything:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var dropDown = $('.dropdown');
$('h3.about').on('click', function () {
    dropDown.slideDown('fast', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'about2.php',
            success: function () {
                var missionWrap = $('#mission-wrap');
                var w = $(window);
                w.on('load resize', function () {
                    missionWrap.css({
                        width: w.width(),
                        height: w.height()
                    });
                });
                var missionContent = $('#mission-content');
                var w = $(window);
                w.on('load resize', function () {
                    missionContent.css({
                        width: w.width() - 205
                    });
                });
            };
        });
    });
});
```

});

Comment: Doing a single-page-app correctly in a way that's usable is a lot of work. Are you sure an animated sidebar is worth the bother?

Comment: It is. I've done single page sites before, so I'm familiar with it - http://www.chiaroscurofnd.org/. It's just the ajax that's throwing me off.

Comment: Are the mystery-meat-link paintings on that page supposed to flicker around in an epileptically-inducing fashion until the subpage is done loading? That site's subpages also aren't bookmarkable.

Comment: Consider rewording your title, as it is completely devoid of any meaning as it is.

Comment: @lanzz Sorry about that, I corrected it.

Comment: And @millimoose, I appreciate your positive attitude.

Comment: @jtrinker Well, what I'm trying to say is that there's more things you're missing about doing single-page applications well. (I.e. not breaking the back button, bookmarkability, and keeping "state transitions" fluid and unobtrusive.) I just couldn't resist when the site that's your claim to competence becomes obviously broken after the first click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
function resize_me () {
    var w = $(window);
    var missionWrap = $('#mission-wrap');
    var missionContent = $('#mission-content');
    missionWrap.css({ width:w.width(), height:w.height()});
    missionContent.css({ width:w.width() - 205 });
}

//Dropdown
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).on('load resize', function () {
        resize_me();
    });
    var dropDown = $('.dropdown');
    $('h3.about').on('click', function() {
        dropDown.slideDown('fast', function() {
            var url = 'about2.php'

            $.get(url, function(data) {
                resize_me();
            });
        });
    });
}
```

I believe that the problem was that the load event that you were attaching to the window object was not being triggered by the successful load of the $.get.

Comment: Thanks so much @manishie! It works wonderfully. I very much appreciate the time you took to do that. I hope I can help you with something in the future.

Comment: Won't $(window).on('load resize', function () {
        resize_me();
    }); call the methods resize_me() twice, first time the page loads?

Comment: AFAIK, it will not call it twice (though this may depend on the browser).  I just did a quick test displaying an alert attached to both the load and resize events, and it only displayed once on window load.

Comment: Your are absolutely right. On mac in both Safari and Firefox it is called twice. But on Pc it is only called once.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rough outline of how to structure your application to handle this correctly.

Assuming your HTML looks something like this:

```html
<html>
...
<div id="index-wrap">
    <!-- this is the reloadable part -->
    ...
</div>
...
</html>
```

You need to refactor all the jQuery enhancements to the elements inside `#index-wrap` to be in a function you can call after a reload:

```js
function enhance(root) {
    $('#some-button-or-whatever', root).on('click', ...);
}
```

(I.e. look up all the elements under the root element that was loaded using AJAX.)

You need to call this function when the page is first loaded, as well as after the AJAX call in the completion callback:

```js
$('#index-wrap').load('/foo.php', function() {
    enhance(this);
});
```

You can also potentially get rid of some of this using *delegated* ("live") events, but it's best to hit the [jQuery documentation on how those work](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

As for events bound to `window` or DOM elements which aren't loaded dynamically, you shouldn't need to rebind them at all based on which subpage is loaded, just check which of your elements loaded is in a handler that you set up once:

```
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
    var $missionContent = $('#missionContent');
    if ($missionContent.length) {
        $missionContent.css(...);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This clears a lot of things up for me. Also, I appreciate the feedback on the chiarascuro site. Can you point me to any information on getting the back button to trigger a smooth scroll?

Comment: @jtrinker You'll need to use the [`pushState()` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) to make the browser recognize "fake" navigation. When calling this method, you can associate an arbitrary object describing the state you're navigating to. You then listen to [`window.onpopstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onpopstate); in the handler for that event, you trigger the corresponding transition to get to the state the event describes.